# Best practice CoreData - separate entity for sequential primitives or embed within the referring entity?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I was wondering if a CoreData guru can offer some advice on the best way or organising the model for my current project...

I have a Patient entity for which I will be recording a number of parameters over time. It makes sense for Patient and Parameter to be entities as they have associated descriptive information but the actual measurements I'm not so sure about.

If I make a Measurement (which will be a tuple composed of a Date and a Double) an entity, it will need a relationship to a Parameter and all of the Parameters for all of the Patients will (I suspect) form one massive SQL-Lite table. If I embed the Measurement within the Parameter entity for a given patient (saving as a Transformable type) then I would keep things a bit more granular and I would expect the performance to be better.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research on this question, the consensus is that it is best to avoid placing collections (e.g. arrays) of data within an entity. Use of separate entities makes searching the data significantly easier and less code-heavy so I have decided to follow this approach.